# Mysql sentence to Sql Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am really new in Sql Server..

I would like to know how to transform this mysql query in Sql Server query.

```
SELECT address
     , name
     , lat
     , lng
     , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * 
            cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) +
                    sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < '%s' 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

I have been trying to get it work but no success

```
SELECT [address],
       [name],
       [lat],
       [lng],
       ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('10') ) *
        cos( radians( 37.353648) ) * cos( radians( -121.997766 ) - radians('10') ) + 
            sin( radians('10') ) * sin( radians( 37.353648 ) ) ) ) AS [distance]
FROM [DesaInterno].[dbo].[marcadores]
where [distance] < 2
```

> Invalid column name 'distance'.

regards

Comment: "query", not "sentence". And we are not a code translation service. You try converting it, we'll (maybe) try help fix whatever you end up with.

Comment: Do you mind providing the SQL statement you had attempted to write?

Comment: You could use something like this: select top 20 * from (select your_query_here) tmp where distance < xxx order by distance

Comment: As @MarcB said, we are not a code translation service. So please first try yourself and let us know if you come across an issue. This link may help you get started. It's a reference to trignometric functions in SQL Server. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191457(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use column aliases in the *where* clause if you are writing a Sql Server query. You should repeat the aliased expression in the *where* clause  (or maybe you can try by using a derived table).

So:

```
SELECT [address],
       [name],
       [lat],
       [lng],
       ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('10') ) *
        cos( radians( 37.353648) ) * cos( radians( -121.997766 ) - radians('10') ) + 
            sin( radians('10') ) * sin( radians( 37.353648 ) ) ) ) AS [distance]
FROM [DesaInterno].[dbo].[marcadores]
where ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('10') ) *
        cos( radians( 37.353648) ) * cos( radians( -121.997766 ) - radians('10') ) + 
            sin( radians('10') ) * sin( radians( 37.353648 ) ) ) ) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just use a subquery to filter out the distance like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [address]
        ,[name]
        ,[lat]
        ,[lng]
        ,(6371 * acos(cos(radians('10')) * cos(radians(37.353648)) 
              * cos(radians(- 121.997766) - radians('10')) 
              + sin(radians('10')) * sin(radians(37.353648)))) AS [distance]
        FROM [DesaInterno].[dbo].[marcadores]
        ) a
    WHERE a.distance < 2
    ORDER BY a.distance
```

Just to point out the problem in your query, you are using aliased [distance] column in the where clause which is computed column, therefore the alias cannot be used directly in the `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, I think you have got it down pretty well.